# How to Update HTML website once its already on?

Tags: html, adobe-brackets

So I do not quite know if THIS website is the actual place to ask this question so please forgive me if it does not cooperate with question asking standards.

I am currently making a website with HTML and I am using Brackets as my editor. Now once I purchase a domain and I post my website and it is finally on the open web ready for commercial use, what if I need to change some information or add some pages?

Will I have to just open up the code using Brackets, edit it, and somehow replace it in the place where I put it in the first place? Or is there some sort of program that I can use that can update this?

I am just asking for suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, just replace the files on the server with the new ones. sftp is your friend.

Comment: Download Filezilla, its free. Watch a youtube video on how to set it up to your hosted domain. Its super simple and really straight forward once you are conneted.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question and will likely be removed, however I'll point you in the right direction.

The exact steps to update your website will depend on your web host and the server you have set up, but in general you want an FTP/SFTP client that will connect to your server and let you upload files (I recommend [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client)). All you do is connect to the IP address of your website and log in, then upload the new versions of the files to your website. It may take a few minutes to propagate and you may have to refresh the page, however that's all there is to it. For further help, just Google a tutorial on Filezilla.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will be using Filezilla, thank you!